# RSS time format to human readable format

Tags: php, datetime, rss, datetime-format, magpie

I'm using [MagpieRSS](http://magpierss.sourceforge.net/) to parse some Craigslist feeds.

The problem is the publish dates for craigslist posts are in this format: `2010-02-25T18:09:38-06:00`

How can I convert that to `Thursday, February 25, 2010 6:09 PM`
using php?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
date('l, F d, Y h:i A', strtotime($the_date));
```

[date()](http://php.net/date)

edit:

```
date(DATE_RFC822, strtotime($the_date));
```

is close, but doesn't match your requirements exactly (i.e. it uses abbreviated days / months, 24hour time and includes a timezone string) as specified in [RFC822](http://www.faqs.org/rfcs/rfc822.html)

Comment: This works except it shows the time 1 hour ahead of what's on the rss feed, although that may not have to do with formatting.

Comment: @Chad: If your server's timzezone is not GMT-0600 that would explain the difference.

Comment: Makes sense, that's what I was thinking. Thanks.

Comment: or just `date(DATE_RSS, strtotime($the_date))`